# My mac has port 49176 open, what is it?

Tags: firewall, port

Does anyone know what port 49176 means on a Mac? I cannot find any info on this particular port. I'm on Mountain Lion, and using `nmap` from Ubuntu machine to test the Mac's firewall.

This is what `nmap` says:

```
PORT      STATE SERVICE
80/tcp    open  http
49176/tcp open  unknown
```

Comment: Please open Terminal, type `lsof -i -P | grep 49176` and report back.

Comment: @jaume no output for that command.

Comment: And what is the output of `nmap`? Can you add it to your question?

Comment: @jaume yes edited it out :)

Comment: And what does `netstat -an | grep 49176` say? (Run it also inside Terminal on your Mac.)

Comment: Is this port open even after you close all applications? I would guess this is something like Skype, Dropbox or some other peer to peer application opening random high ports possibly for NAT traversal.

Comment: @PeterJenkins well it disappeared. netstat -an | grep 49176 doesn't display anything, and nmap also stoped showing it. MY guess is same Skype or ubd

Comment: Next time this happens, run `lsof -i -P | grep <port>` on the Mac, you will see the application that binds to that port. If the Mac's firewall is active it must be one of the applications listed in System Preferences>Security & Privacy>Firewall with comment *Allow incoming connections*.